# Using a for loop to allow the user to put in an input from 1-100

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

Just starting out with for loops and I'm kinda stumped on this question. In the code below I was able to create an array with size of 4. I need to be able to allow the users to put in 4 different integers that range from 1-100 and store it in a array.

I would also need to make sure that the user doesn't input anything that is less than 0 or larger than 100. In this case I was thinking using a try-catch method. Would that be possible in a for loop? Please advise:

```
 const int SIZE = 4;
int[] array = new int[SIZE];
int numberOfTests = 4;

for (int count = 0; count < numberOfTests; count++) // Start the count from 0-4
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = 100;

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter test score " + count); 
}
```

Comment: Compesating on the minus 1 you got, not because your question is well written - it's not. But, I think you did try to write a "good" questions. Try using standard input methods (google "c# input from user"), and check value (if clause) brfore you insert the value into the array.

Comment: Sorry if I'm bad at asking "good" questions. I, myself is fairly new to this site as well as to coding. I do what I can, and try to ask questions so that others can lead me in the right directions rather flat out giving me the answer. This gives me the opportunity to learn and be able to "see" what I've built. To be honest, I dont really care if you down vote as this is just a learning experience for me to improve my skills.

Comment: I get that. That's why I compensated on the minus one somone gave you, with a plus one of my own. Keep going forward with a good spirit and a learning will. That's the most important thing! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would change it to this based on what I think you want to do:

```
        const int SIZE = 4;
        int[] array = new int[SIZE];
        int numberOfTests = 4;

        for (int count = 0; count < numberOfTests; count++) // Start the count from 0-4
        {
            int min = 0;
            int max = 100;

            int countf = count + 1;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter test score " + countf);
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (a > 0 && a < 101)
            {
                array[count] = a;
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
        Console.WriteLine(array[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(array[1]);
        Console.WriteLine(array[2]);
        Console.WriteLine(array[3]);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and catch isn't for testing the inputs conditions thats what an if statement is for. 
Try and catch if for testing that the code is able to run and if not providing an alternative. So for example if a user entered a string a try and catch statement would stop the program crashing. Hope this helps

```
const int numberOfTests = 4;
int[] array = new int[numberOfTests];

for (int count = 0; count < numberOfTests; count++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter test score " + count);
    try
    {
        int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (answer > 0 && answer < 101)
             array[count] = answer;
        else Console.WriteLine("Please provide a value between 1-100");

    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please provide an integer");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read())` this is a one way street to an unhandled exception

Comment: I've just changed it to readLine when you pointed it out but its in a try and catch so it Is handled.

Comment: Sorry i over looked that, however truth be known exceptions should not dictate the flow of an application, `TryParse` is a much better solution. anyway ill leave you with it

Comment: @JackSanderson - Please never write `catch { ... }` in code. It just swallows errors and will eventually cause you to ship buggy code and/or take you a day to figure out why your code isn't working. You should only ever catch a specific exception that you can meaningfully handle and that you can't reasonably code an alternative. In this code the specific exception is `FormatException`, but you can reasonably code `TryParse` as an alternative so that should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to use try-catch in "correct scenario". You seem to need to catch every input exception while you were thinking using try catch method.
In this case, I'll suggest defining a new integer class for you. since you want to use try-catch. Throw an exception for the input data out of range or whatever you expect to be.
The code will be like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class MyInt
{
    public MyInt(int i)
    {
        Data = i;
    }

    private int _data;
    public int Data
    {
        get => _data;
        set
        {
            if(value<0||value>100)throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            _data = value;
        }
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    MyInt[] array = new MyInt[4];

    int min = 0;
    int max = 100;
    for (int count = 0; count < array.Length; count++) // Start the count from 0-4
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter test score " + count);
        try
        {
            array[count] = new MyInt(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Input exception :{exception}/n, Please input a valid number between {min} and {max}");
            count--;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"The array result here, eg. Sum of all :{array.Sum(i=>i.Data)}");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```